# Adding first and last name to Wordpress registration form

Tags: php, wordpress

My registration form on WP only had the options Username, e-mail and password.

```
//1. firstname
```

add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

```
$first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>

    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

In my registration form (template) I've placed the following:

```
                <label><?php _e('First Name', APP_TD) ?></label>
                <input tabindex="3" type="text" name="first_name" class="text regular-text" id="display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" maxlength="100" />
```

And it works as it should. It grabs the first name and places it in the user profile. However I'm not sure on how to add the last name to it aswell, I'm quite a beginner, and for some reason I can't get the last name to work. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never worked with something like that on my WP. Where have you put this code?

However I would try to execute something like this:

```
//1. Fistname

add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' ); function myplugin_register_form() {

$first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
$last_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

?>

<?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
    $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) == '' ) {
    $errors->add( 'last_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a last name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name']  ));
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. Forgot to mention I tried your method already. It returns an error and says that the last name field hasn't been filled in, even though it has. I've placed the code in my functions.php and the other part inside my registration-template.

Comment: NVM, your code did work, thanks!. Seems I forgot to change the last name attribute inside name=""

Comment: If it worked, can you mark my answer as resolved for your question ? :) Thanks